# Typescript Visitor Pattern missing type info

Tags: typescript, visitor-pattern

I seem to be losing type info using the visitor design pattern in typescript:

```
abstract class AbsVisitor
{
  public abstract visitPerson(p: Person): void;
  public abstract visitAddress(p: Address): void;
}

class StrVisitor extends AbsVisitor
{
  public visitPerson(p: Person): void {
    console.log(`XXX ${typeof p}  XXX`) // <--- type Person is lost !
    console.log(`name: ${p.name}`);
  }
  public visitAddress(a: Address): void {
    console.log(`XXX ${typeof a}  XXX`) // <--- type Address is lost !
    console.log(`{a.street}( ${a.num} )`);
  }
}

class Person {
  constructor(public name: string){}
  public accept(v: AbsVisitor){ v.visitPerson(this); }
}

class Address {
  constructor(public street: string, public num: number){}
  public accept(v: AbsVisitor){ v.visitAddress(this); }
}

let v = new StrVisitor();
let p = new Person("moish");
let a = new Address("5th Ave.", 62);
p.accept(v);
a.accept(v);
```

When I run it, I get the sub-optimal (incorrect?) result:

```
XXX object  XXX
name: moish
XXX object  XXX
{a.street}( 62 )
```

Comment: Using `typeof` at runtime will not display the compile time type. It correctly outputs `object` which is the JavaScript type for all objects. (There is no way to output the compile time type of `p` or `a` at runtime) - actually since they are classes, you can do `p.constructor.name`. But this will only work for classes.

Comment: @TobiasS. that is unfortunate ! any idea how to debug it? dynamic casting? I mean something like logging properties of the static type

Comment: JavaScript does not have casting outside of primitives. But what is the problem you are trying to solve? Just displaying the type?

Comment: I have a complex visiting layout - I'm trying to log the exact visit details for further process

Comment: [Runtime typesafety in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135732) | [What is type erasure?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure)

Comment: In the example code of your question, you have one function for each `class` anyway. You can log whatever you want depending on the specific class.

Comment: @TobiasS. the example is just a demonstration - my real life case involves a situation where knowing the type would help *a lot*

Comment: I guess you should also include an example in the question where knowing the type would be helpful.